# Cannot use Macro in a C++ constructor?

Tags: c++, macros

I have a complex class that I was trying to simplify with a Macro.  The Macro works fine with some compilers, but not with others.  I was thinking that a macro was just text replacement, am I wrong?

```
struct FooManager
{
    FooManager(){}
    void Add( Foo* i_pFoo ){ m_FooObjects.Add( i_pFoo ); }
private:
    DynamicArray<Foo*> m_FooObjects;
};

struct Foo
{
   Foo( FooManager& mgr, int param1, int param2 = 0 )
       : m_Param1( param1 )
       , m_Param2( param2 )
   {
       mgr.Add( this );
   }
private:
    const int m_Param1, m_Param2;
}

class Bar
{
    FooManager m_Manager;
    Foo m_Foo1, m_Foo2;
public:
    Bar();
};
```

Then in the .cpp file...

```
#define Macro( f, a, ... ) f( m_Manager, a, __VA_ARGS__ )

Bar::Bar()
    : m_Manager()
    , Macro( m_Foo1, 1 )
    , Macro( m_Foo2, 2, 3 )
{}
```

I get an "error 29: expected an expression" when using a gcc compiler.

All I really want is my Bar to have a Manager that knows about all of the Foo's in it.  I can unroll the Macro, but was hoping I didn't have to because it makes things look a lot cleaner, and it can provide other shared parameters based on usage.

I am inclined to believe that there is a rule I am breaking by doing this, and that the compilers that it does work with are for some reason ignoring this rule.

Comment: You should look on preprocessor output to debug it.

Comment: `: m_Manager, ` What are you doing here?

Comment: You don't list m_Manager in the initialization list if you're not passing any arguments to its constructor.

Comment: @RobK: Actually you can, but it needs empty parentheses.

Comment: Correct, sorry.  My pseudo code was wrong.  I am simplifying from my more complex real life example.  FooManager also has parameters, that for the purposes of my question are irrelevant.  Suffice it to say that it needs to be initialized before the Foo objects are.

Comment: @RobK, @JameyD `m_Manager` *is* listed in the initilization list; the macro tries to initialize `m_foo[12]` (passing their CTORs the `m_Manager`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations when `__VA_ARGS__` is empty (e.g. when expanding `Macro( m_Foo1, 1 )`) your macro will generate the following entry in the constructor initializer list

```
m_Manager(<some argument>, )
```

This is obviously invalid. The idea of `__VA_ARGS__` is that you should supply at least one argument for the `__VA_ARGS__` part.

In order to make `__VA_ARGS__` easier to use in such contexts, compilers like MSVC are known to implement non-standard behavior in this case: they quietly remove the excessive comma, making your original code to compile as intended.

GCC also implements a non-standard extension that serves the same purpose, but you have to activate it by using a non-standard trick with `##`

```
#define Macro( f, a, ... ) f( m_Manager, a, ##__VA_ARGS__ )
```

This will automatically remove the trailing comma in GCC when `__VA_ARGS__` is empty.

Comment: Aha! You nailed it.  So I have another option...
 
    #define Macro( f, ... ) f( m_Manager, __VA_ARGS__ )

Thank you!